# creating new columns but get earning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

I always get this warning when I try to create a column, what can I do differently? Thank you.

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  foodie['Age'] = foodie['questions_135557_how_old_are_you']
```

[image]

Comment: This is a warning, not an error

Comment: The thing that is difficult to understand about this warning is it is letting you know that you are _setting_ to a copy of a slice. Meaning, that `foodie` is _already_ a copy of some dataframe when you try to create a new column. At some point __before__ these lines you must have done something like `foodie = df[some columns]`, when you should have done something like `foodie = df[some columns].copy()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a warning, not an error, but one you should handle
If you're just trying to change the names of the columns, use the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method

```py
foodie = foodie.rename(columns={
    'questions_135557_how_old_are_you': 'Age',
    'questions_134999_where_are_you_eating_at_the_moment': 'Location'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning.  If you want to hide the error put this line after the `import pandas as pd` line...

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

If you want to see them again comment it out and restart the kernel.

Comment: This is not really what they want though, they'll end up with _new_ columns (for which they would want to use `.loc[:, "Age"]`), _and_ not see the warning which has helped lead them here and alert that something is up! it appears they want to _rename_ the columns, which they can do with `.rename()`